# Magit, how to use system's ssh agent and don't ask for password

Tags: magit, linux, ssh

I've googled and read the FAQ and Wiki for Magit, but still unable to figure this out, all I find are answers about Windows...

How can I configure Magit to use my running ssh-agent session and don't ask for my password when doing a push.

I'm running linux, and have the ssh-agent startup with my terminal and unlock my key then, which allows me to do git push, etc. without having me enter the password each time.

Env:
Arch Linux
Emacs 24.4

ssh-agent with keys added, to unlock on first terminal opened.

**EDIT:** I meant using passphrase, you know for the ssh key, et al.
And I'm pushing to Bitbucket, but I do believe the key problem is that Magit is not talking/recognizing my ssh-agent.
Maybe there's some config to set, to tell it that I'm running it??

Comment: Actually came with the same question.

Comment: What is the remote url? http:// or git:// ?

Comment: git@bitbucket.org in this case, setup like so: url = git@bitbucket.org:

Comment: Can you tell us what Emacs is returning when you do `M-x getenv SSH_AGENT_PID`? `M-x getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Comment: SSH_AGENT_PID = 602 SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/ssh-13kI6AaYvgji/agent.601

Comment: And do you get the same from `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` in the shell? Also, please elaborate on "have the ssh-agent startup with my terminal and unlock my key".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well this turned out to be more of a rabbit hole than I though... And for what I can gather there's not a better solution for this specific issue, with this combination of desktop, ssh-agent, emacs.

**Problem 1**
XFCE was starting it's own ssh-agent with the session, without actually saying so anywhere, which caused the system to have 1 unused global ssh-agent, and my shell specific unlocked agent.
On a different DE you might run with the same problem, and will need to find the specifics to disable the agent auto start.

**Solution 1**
Run this command to disable the startup ssh-agent from executing

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/ssh-agent/enabled -n -t bool -s false`

**Problem 2**
Now Emacs does not have any **SSH_AGENT_PID** and **SSH_AUTH_SOCK** variables set, so nothing on the loaded environment. Obviously Magit still asks for the key as it doesn't know about the new **ssh-agent** we started.

**Solution 2**
We need to have Emacs fetch up these new variables from the enviroment, but of course, no straight forward way.
Enter: [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) that allows you to fetch environment variables from your shell.
So.

1. Install the ***exec-path-from-shell*** package in your preferred way.
2. Add the following code to your **init.el** so that it loads when you start Emacs.

`(require 'exec-path-from-shell)
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "SSH_AGENT_PID")
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")`

Thanks guys for the suggestion on looking at the SSH_** variables, that pointed me on the right direction.

Comment: Any particular reason you are not satisfied with XFCE's agent and want to run your own?  Abandoning that would seem like the simpler solution.

Comment: I not always run XFCE, nor do I care on how the desktop manages it, I prefer the plugin that handles it from oh-my-zsh. So it's easier for me to skip the default use case. (granted I don't know nearly enough about the agent... but is not something I really want to spend time thinking about anyway)

Comment: Maybe Zsh should recognize the case when an agent is already running, and defer to that instead; but obviously, this is getting off-topic here.

Comment: Maybe [ssh-agency](https://github.com/magit/ssh-agency) should be extended to work on unix-like systems too.

Answer (score 18):

Another solution for the lazy is to just use a package that handles exactly this case (setting Emacs' keychain-related environment variables):

1. Install and add to your init.el package [keychain-environment](https://github.com/tarsius/keychain-environment/blob/master/keychain-environment.el#L27-L48).
2. Run `M-x keychain-refresh-environment` and now it should work.
3. Place `(keychain-refresh-environment)` in your init.el, so the solution works after restarting Emacs

And that's all, assuming your ssh-agent is configured and running.

Really good description, from package's comment:

> Keychain is a script that manages ssh-agent and gpg-agent.  It is
>   typically run from the shell's initialization file.  It allows your
>   shells and cron jobs to share a single ssh-agent and/or gpg-agent.
>
> When keychain is run, it checks for running agent, otherwise it
>   starts them.  It saves the agents' environment variables to files
>   inside ~/.keychain/, so that subsequent shells can source these
>   files.
>
> When Emacs is started under X11 and not directly from a terminal
>   these variables are not set.  This library looks for these files
>   created by keychain and then sets Emacs' environment variables
>   accordingly.  It does not actually run keychain, so you still
>   have to run that from a login shell first.
>
> To use run the function `keychain-refresh-environment' in your
>   init file.  If keychain has not been run yet when you start Emacs
>   you can also later call that function interactively.
>
> Also see: http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain

Comment: This is exactly what I needed since I already use `keychain`.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, `keychain` now has a `--systemd` switch, which will inject the variables into the systemd user environment.

The simplest solution I found was to add `eval "$(keychain --eval --quiet --noask --systemd keys...)"` to a script that's ran from the systemd unit to start the Emacs server.

Comment: I am trying this solution, where exactly I need to put the script. I am running emacs daemon under systemd. Should I put under `ExecPostStart`

Comment: Put the script in `ExecStart` and put the command to start the Emacs server in the script, after the `eval`.