# Magit how to use ssh key rather than being prompted for password

Tags: magit, git, ssh, github, passwords

I've seen the question here but I'm not sure if the same solution would apply to me

[Magit, how to use system's ssh agent and don't ask for password](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17866/magit-how-to-use-systems-ssh-agent-and-dont-ask-for-password/17890#17890)

I'm on Emacs 25.1 / Ubuntu 16.04. I've just set up SSH-keys according to https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/ and I've added the public key to my GitHub account.

When I try to push though, Magit prompts me for my password to my account foobar@github.com (as always) rather than seeing that I've set an SSH-key into ssh-agent.

`M-x getenv SSH_AGENT_PID` doesn't exist and `M-x getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is  `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` is 18145. What is the next step from here?

Comment: `M-x setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 18145`?

Answer (score 5):

Edit `~/.ssh/config` so that it contains the following:

```
Host github.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key
```

Then whenever magit asks git to ask ssh to talk to github.com, ssh will know what key to use; saves a lot of mucking about.

Comment: The issue was I had the remote url set to https instead of ssh, I posted an answer for other people to see. I think you answer is useful for learning more about how the ~/.ssh/config works though, I think I'll need to refer to it in the future, thanks

Comment: So close and yet so far... I put this on, but then Magit ends up in a loop. No matter how many times I type the password correctly, the prompt comes back.

Comment: If you use this configuration, and your git repository is using an ssh url, then Magit will not ask you for your github password. It might ask you for the password to your ssh key though, if the key is password protected. Are you sure you entered the correct password?

Comment: It says `Enter passphrase for key ...`, so I believe it is asking for the password to the correct file, which is the exact same I've been using with my terminal and Vim for quite a while. I've tested the password on the terminal a dozen times, it's the same.

Comment: Could be a bug, but check first to see if Magit is just performing multiple operations. Use `$` to open a log buffer before you do whatever you do that needs the key.

Comment: I've created a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67423957/4756173) about this issue on StackOverflow, as I believe it is broader than only Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that the remote url was set to https rather than ssh

following these steps fixed the issue https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/